# Bypass the save dialog box of fileReference.save

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

Can we Bypass the save dialog box of FileRefernce.save()?

If not, then Is there any workaround to save a file from web application in Flex without asking user where to save file?

I am using FP10.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can if you use the [flash.fileSystem](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/package-detail.html) API in an AIR application, but as far as i know it's not possible with browser-resident Flash.

if it's not, you might be able to call a JavaScript routine with [flash.external.ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) that can do it for you - assuming it's possible to do what you want with JavaScript.

**[edit]** for security reasons, i really can't imagine that this is possible with JavaScript either.

**[edit 2]**  the best you'll be able to do is use a [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) to read and write your XML data, but it's sandboxed and possible for the user to turn off or limit available space, so you'll have to be cautious.

Comment: Actually i want to update a xml file stored in applicationDirectory at runtime from a browser-based application.


Comment: where is the applicationDirectory of a browser based Flash application?  read my second edit.

Comment: :D can't use sharedObject as it has limitation of space.

Comment: the default storage setting for a browser-based Flash application is 100Kb, which should be more than enough for a general XML file.  most users are not going to reduce this space and/or even know they can reduce the amount of storage that Flash Player allows.  as long as you have a fallback or notify the user if and when the data couldn't be saved you should be fine.

Comment: @Gannesh, applicatonDirectory *is not* available for web based projects.  I don't see why you need to store *anything* on the client computer.  If you need to save simple preferences, used SharedObject (similar to cookie, but Flash based).  If you need more info (especially if you need it to be persisted across different computer), save those settings to your server which can be retrieved the next time the user logs in.

Comment: @J_A_X, Yeah i got it now. :) Thanks!!

Comment: +1 for "thank god random sites can't save to my HDD at will", right?  ;)